The usage of "any other" with nouns
If the modifier any is used with singular and plural nouns, and other is only used with plural nouns (and uncontable), why when the word any is used before other estabilishes which form will take the nouns? I mean, both are determiners.

Are there other options available for the menu?


Is there any other doctor available right now?


"Is there any other doctor" or "Are there any other doctors" are both valid. It depends how many doctors you want or are interested in.

Your rule may be off. "Besides gruel, do you offer other food?" "No other road gets you there as fast."

@YosefBaskin Food is uncountable in your example (You could also say "other foods"). Negation also changes things and can be used with singular. "No road gets you there from here".

Your premise, “other is only used with plural nouns (and uncontable),” is false.

With count noun usages, the indefinite article is compounded with 'other' (if 'any' is not chosen): 'Is there another option available for the menu?'

“Isn’t there at least one other doctor available right now?”   Here we are literally counting.
